# join xml element.text in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml.etree

Is there some function in python for joining element.text with the same Element.tag names?

Example:

```
 p>     
        some text
        <i>(</i>
        <i>something</i>
        <i>something</i>
        <i>)</i>
        some text
        <i>proň, zač</i>
        the end of paragraph
    </p>
```

What I want:

```
 p>     
        some text
        <i>(something something)</i>
        some text
        <i>proň, zač</i>
        the end of paragraph
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some function in python for joining element.text with same tags name?

No, you must code it yourself. The reason is that the library deals with xml, not just xhtml. In general, `<tag>a</tag><tag>b</tag>` does not have the same meaning as `<tag>ab</tag>`. In fact, even in html, consolidating adjacent `<p>` or `<block>` tags would change the meaning of the text.